# ruby object add property path from string

Tags: ruby, properties

I have a function that traverses through a remote object tree.
I pass various  existing property-paths to each object to get their values.
simplified like this:

```
def treetrav(node_list, property_path_list)
    node-list.each do |node|
        property_path_list.each{|prop| puts (node + prop)}
        # puts node.config.name    works like a charm
    end
end

prop_lst = [".config.name", ".config.hardware"]
treetrav(rootnode, prop_lst)
```

example propertypath:
node.config.name
or 
node.config.hardware.label
so something like node + (propertypath) or join() was my attempt but i get various "undefined method"errors, do I need to add these manually?

since i can not find any reference anywhere the solution must be so plain simple that i can not see it or my whole concept for this is bogus.
I just picked up ruby so any pointers would be appreciated.

err_out:
undefined method `+' for # (NoMethodError)

I do understand the error, I just thought there would be some way to just add the property-tail to the node object.

Comment: Give examples on how you call that function and the errors you are getting

Comment: Also you are missing 2 `end`. And in ruby you name variables and methods with the underscore notation instead of dash

Comment: edited.
The treetraversal itself works, i just want to pass that specific element from property_path_list to the node object so the whole property path is complete.
By the way you ask, i guess my whole approach is wrong